# Passing parameter to ireport by jsp

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jasper-reports

I developed a report using iReport. The report is supposed to run in several different databases.

In the report I've put several parameters, some of them contains date format. Everything goes well at the beginning when I'm using `to_date(<parameter variable>)`.

But now it seems this method can't be run on Postgres, so I tried not to use `to_date()`.

I just leave it as

`ex: date = $P{date}`

and i change the initial value to

`new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse("01/01/2011")`.

There is no error when compilling, but when i run through application, it appear error caused by:

`java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 3C68746D.`

Later I tried to change the parameter type to `String` (from `java.util.Date`) and put `""` as it initial value.

It works well, **except for Oracle database**. Can someone help me?

Comment: Hi, dont' know if I get your question right. If you want to cast from an oracle datefield to char. `select to_char(ora_datefield,'DD/MM/YYYY')as mydate from mytable;`

Comment: correct, but i want to do it as parameter. and i want to use the same query and same report template that can successfully run in three different database, mysql, oracle, postgres.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I guess you've realized that you were trying to put String values on date fields, when you did `new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse("01/01/2011")`, right?

I don't know if I get you right, but I guess the field in your data base is Date, so you must use dates, not strings. The final format conversion (that will result in a string) must be in your report template or whatever you're using. But the database will return dates to your API.

Comment: "The final format conversion (that will result in a string) must be in your report template or whatever you're using. But the database will return dates to your API." i didnt understand this part, im sorry. Did u mean new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse("01/01/2011") will output string type? Thanks 4 your concern.

Comment: I meant that you will send and receive dates to the database. the flow will be with dates, not strings. The final format conversion, (that will convert date to string) will be perform in your report api, and no more communicating with the database.

Comment: that means when i use java.util.date() as parameter and new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse("01/01/2011") as it initial value, its suppose to be ok right? but why when i run through application it send error? this error : java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 3C68746D. im using Oracle database.

Comment: please, post the entire stack trace and a more clear piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the the date in the format of string and in 'DD/MM/YYYY' format to i-report from your code.

In i-report write the query in this format (change the format of the date compared to suit the input):

`to_date('fieldnameofDB','DD/MM/YYYY')=$P{nameOfParameterPassed}`

Just change the way you accept the parameter, set the format of the parameter to String.